# popup does not clear after the drop down items are selected and closed in angular 7

Tags: angular

I have implemented a modal window control. I have a Add button on the form. Clicking the Add button opens the modal window. I have written the code to clear the controls in the modal window. The modal window has three drop down selection controls. Its clears the first time when i open the window. If i select values in the drop down and close the window , the values are retained when i try to open the window again. I am not sure why my clearing logic doesnt take effect then. Please see the method openClassificationOverrideModal which has code with a comment against it that tells which method is called to clear the popup. The shared-modal in the parent component markup is the modal component.

Parent component html

```
<div style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; "> 
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="panel panel-default col-md-12  ">
        <div *ngIf="ClassificationOverrideDetails && ClassificationOverrideDetails.ClassificationEntities" class="panel-body">
                <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="openClassificationOverrideModal('Add',null)" type="button" >Add new Classification</button>
            <div id="grid-wrapper" [style.height.px]="GridHeight()" [style.width.%]="100" style="float: left;">
                <ag-grid-angular #agGrid class="ag-theme-balham" [gridOptions]="GridOptions"
                    style="width: 100%; height: 100%" [columnDefs]="ColumnDefs"
                    [rowData]="ClassificationOverrideDetails.ClassificationEntities" rowHeight="30" headerHeight="30"
                    rowSelection="single">
                </ag-grid-angular>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div> 

<div *ngIf="ClassificationOverrideDetails  && ClassificationOverrideDetails.ReferenceData">
        <shared-modal [modalSize]="1" class="survey-edit" [open]="classficationOverrideWindowOpened">
            <div style="width: 100%;" header>
                <h4 class="modal-title"> Classification Overrides
                    <div style="text-align: right"><button aria-label="Dismiss" class="close"
                            style="margin-top: -48px" style="margin-top: -48px" type="button"
                            (click)="dismissClassificationOverrideModal()">X</button></div>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div body>
                <edit-classification-override (ClassficationOverrideDetailsEvent)="init($event)" (SelectedClassficationEntityEvent) = "onNotify($event)" [IsRefreshed] = "IsRefreshed" [SelectedClassficationEntities] = "SelectedClassficationEntities" [ClassificationOverrideDetails]= "ClassificationOverrideDetails" ></edit-classification-override>

            </div>
            <div footer>
            </div>
        </shared-modal>
</div>
```

Parent component

```
openClassificationOverrideModal(val: string, selectedClassificationId: number) {
        if (this.editClassficationOverrideComponent != null) {
            if (val === ADD) {
                 this.editClassficationOverrideComponent.init(ADD, selectedClassificationId);  // Method called in child component to clear. This results in executing the else part
                 this.ClassificationOverrideDetails.ClassificationEntities = {};
                 this.ClassificationOverrideDetails.ClassificationEntities.ID = 0;
                 this.ClassificationOverrideDetails.ClassificationEntities.ManagerStrategyId = this.ManagerStrategyId;
                 this.IsRefreshed = true;
            } else {
                this.editClassficationOverrideComponent.init(EDIT, selectedClassificationId);
                this.ClassificationOverrideDetails.ClassificationEntities.ID = selectedClassificationId;

            }
            this.classficationOverrideWindowOpened = true;

        }
    }
    dismissClassificationOverrideModal() {
        this.classficationOverrideWindowOpened = false;
       this.SelectedClassficationEntities = {};

    }
```

Child component html

```
 <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header panel-heading">
        <span class="left-label" style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; ">{{Mode}} Classification</span>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div *ngIf="ClassificationOverrideDetails" class="card-body" style="width:100%">

            <div class="form-group row">

                <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2 col-form-label modal-label ">Product</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">

                    <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:100%"
                        [(ngModel)]="ProductTypeSelectedItem"
                        class="form-control  form-control-sm"
                        [data]="ClassificationOverrideDetails.ReferenceData.PRODUCT_ID" [filterable]="false"
                        textField="Name" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id"
                        (valueChange)="productChanged($event)">
                    </kendo-dropdownlist>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">

                <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2 col-form-label modal-label ">Reporting Strategy</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">

                    <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:100%"
                        [(ngModel)]="LegacyStrategyTypeSelectedItem"
                        class="form-control  form-control-sm"
                        [data]="ClassificationOverrideDetails.ReferenceData.LEGACY_STRATEGY_ID" [filterable]="false" [valuePrimitive]="true"
                        textField="Name"  (valueChange)="legacyChanged($event)" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id" 
                        >
                    </kendo-dropdownlist>
                </div>

            </div>



            <div class="form-group row">

                <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2 col-form-label modal-label ">Strategy Type</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">

                    <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:100%"
                        [(ngModel)]="ManagerStrategyTypeSelectedItem"
                        [defaultItem]="defaultItem"
                        class="form-control  form-control-sm"
                        [data]="ClassificationOverrideDetails.ReferenceData.MANAGERSTRATEGY_TYPE_ID"
                        [filterable]="false" textField="Name" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id"

                        (valueChange)="managerStrategyTypeChanged($event)">
                    </kendo-dropdownlist>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-toolbar" style="padding-top:40px;">
            <span><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-view-all btn mr-3" (click)="Save()">Save</button>

            </span>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Child component

```
 public init(val: string, selectedClassficationId: number) {
        this.Mode = val;
        if (selectedClassficationId !== null) {
            this.getClassificationDetails(selectedClassficationId);
        } else {
            this.SelectedClassficationEntities = {ID : null, ProductId: null, LegacyStrategyId: null, ManagerStrategyTypeId: null, ManagerStrategyId: null};
           this.clearDropDownList();
        }
    }


   private clearDropDownList() {

    this.ProductTypeSelectedItem = {
        'Id': null,
        'Name': ''
    };
    this.LegacyStrategyTypeSelectedItem = {
        'Id': null,
        'Name': ''
    };
    this.ManagerStrategyTypeSelectedItem = {
        'Id': null,
        'Name': ''
    };

   }


public legacyChanged(value: any): void {
    this.SelectedClassficationEntities.LegacyStrategyId = value;
}

public productChanged(value: any): void {
    this.SelectedClassficationEntities.ProductId = value;
}

public managerStrategyTypeChanged(value: any): void {
    this.SelectedClassficationEntities.ManagerStrategyTypeId  = value;
}
```

Shared modal

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, SimpleChange, SimpleChanges, DoCheck } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;
@Component({
    selector: 'shared-modal',
    templateUrl: './shared-modal.html'
})
export class SharedModal {
    _isopen = false;

    private _modalSize = 1; // 1:normal, 2: medium, 3: large
    public get modalSize() {
        return this._modalSize;
    }

    @Input()
    public set modalSize(value) {
        this._modalSize = value;
    }

    get open(): boolean {
        return this._isopen;
    }

    @Input()
    set open(val: boolean) {
        this._isopen = val;
    }
    getModalDialogClass() {
        if (this.modalSize == null || this.modalSize <= 1 || this.modalSize > 4) {
            return 'modal-dialog modal-sm';
        } else if (this.modalSize <= 2) {
            return 'modal-dialog modal-md';
        } else if (this.modalSize <= 3) {
            return 'modal-dialog modal-lg';
        }  else if (this.modalSize <= 4) {
            return 'modal-dialog modal-xl';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make sure to add a minimal verifiable code snippet for others to take a look and understand your problem. For more details on how to create Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example check https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex.

Comment: I have added as minimum code to understand. Its not the full code

Comment: please create a stackblitz then

Comment: IMO including all of that css styles in your html make it easy to undrestand and focus on your issue

Comment: I basically need to refresh the child component contents hosted in the modal dialog. I tried calling the following method to destroy the child component.     destroyMe() {
        this.elementRef.nativeElement.remove();
      }

Comment: How do I recreate it